# Ionic2 $font-family-base not working

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

The variable `$font-family-base` in Ionic2 is not working.

In the `app.variable.scss` file I added a new value to it, but the old value remains.

Other variables like `$font-size-base` is working fine

Those are my gulp tasks for building `www`:

```
gulp.task("fonts", function () {
    return copyFonts({
        src: [
          "app/fonts/**/*.+(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)"
        ]
    });
});

gulp.task("sass", function () {
    return buildSass({
        sassOptions: {
            includePaths: [
              "node_modules/ionic-angular",
              "node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss"
            ]
        }
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

That is my **font-faces**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Maven Pro";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Maven Pro"), local("Maven-Pro-Regular"), url("#{$font-path}/MavenPro-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Maven Pro";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local("Maven Pro Medium"), local("Maven-Pro-Medium"), url("#{$font-path}/MavenPro-Medium.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Maven Pro";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Maven Pro Bold"), local("Maven-Pro-Bold"), url("#{$font-path}/MavenPro-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Maven Pro";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: local("Maven Pro Ultra Bold"), local("Maven-Pro-Regular-Ultra-Bold"), url("#{$font-path}/MavenPro-Black.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

This **font-faces** are in my `app.scss` file which is referenced in my `app.core.scss`

**app.core.scss**:

```
// http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/

// App Shared Imports
// --------------------------------------------------
// These are the imports which make up the design of this app.
// By default each design mode includes these shared imports.
// App Shared Sass variables belong in app.variables.scss.
@import "../app";

@import "../users/sus/sus";
@import "../users/sus/home/home";
@import "../users/sus/subjects/german/german";
@import "../users/sus/subjects/math/math";
```

**UPDATE:**

If I do it using specific device sass variable i.e:

- $font-family-md-base
- $font-family-ios-base
- $font-family-wp-base

Tha is a wird behavior, but I guess the `$font-family-base` has to be set in a specific order or file, what I still didn't figure out.

Comment: After running the gulp task, can you see the custom font in the build folder?

Comment: yes...the font is there

Comment: Are you adding the font in the `app.variable.scss` using the `@font-face` rule (using the build route)? You can take a look at how to use this rule [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

Comment: yes, I am. I'll update my thread so you can see it

Comment: Last question, sorry... In the compiled css file, has `#{$font-path}` the proper value?

Comment: yes it it. something that is really weirdo, If I fo it for instance in the `app.md.scss` with the `$font-family-md-base` it works fine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just asked [Mike](http://mhartington.io/) (from Ionic Team) and he told me:

> `$font-family-ios-base` is for when it is on an ios device

And the same applies for

```
$font-family-md-base
```

and

```
$font-family-wp-base
```

But I think the key is that:

> `$font-family-base` is when it's **neither** ios or md

I think this explains the behaviour you were talking about. So in your case you would need to change the value of that font in

```
$font-family-md-base
$font-family-ios-base
$font-family-wp-base
```

or any of them to make it work.